# Why is std:: needed in std::get<0>(some_tuple)?

Tags: c++, argument-dependent-lookup

I'd like to benefit from [Argument-Dependent Lookup](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl) when I extract a specific field from a tuple, but the following is illegal according to my compilers:

```
#include <tuple>

int main()
{
    auto t = std::make_tuple<int>(0);
    return get<0>(t);
}
```

> ```
> clang++ --std=c++14 -O2 -Werror -Wall -Wextra -pedantic
>   error: use of undeclared identifier 'get'
> ```

Why, since `t` has a type defined in `::std`, `std::get` is not found after ADL?

Comment: Do you mean `return get<0>(t)`?

Comment: Cannot reproduce. What's your question?

Comment: Yes it was a typo :/